# Is it possible to pass dataframes between R and Python using Arrow with zero-copy?

Tags: python, r

Arrow is an in-memory format, so I can have a dataframe in Python backed by the arrow format. So the dataframe sits in memory, can I use that dataframe directly from R without making a copy of the dataframe? Imagine if the dataframe is 100G in size so copying is very inefficient.

I read in the documentation of Arrow that there is zero-copy *streaming*, but there isn't a way to make the *whole* dataframe available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently, though hopefully very soon. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3750 is in progress and hopefully will resolve in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can according to [the latest Arrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/arrow.html#efficient-data-interchange-between-r-and-python).

- If Python is your “primary” language and R is the “secondary” language. To use R variables and functions inside a Python process, there's [rpy2 package](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.5.x/html/generated_rst/pandas.html#from-r-to-pandas)

```
# this is an example to call an R function with a python pandas data frame argument, and then convert the result R dataframe back into python pandas

# in R: suppose there is an R function 'risk_summary' in an R package 'BCRA', both input and result are data frames
library(BCRA)
result = risk_summary(input)

# in python:
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

# start an R child process in python, import BCRA package in the R process
BCRA = importr('BCRA')

# create the input data frame
input = pandas.DataFrame(#SOME DATA#)

# a wrapping python function to call the 'BCRA.risk_summary' R function
def r_rcra(input):
    with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
        input_r = ro.conversion.py2rpy(input)

    result_r = BCRA.risk_summary(input_r)

    with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
        result = ro.conversion.rpy2py(result_r)

    # NA in R will be translated in a special "rpy2.robjects.NA_Character" object in python, so we need to manually translate it into None in Python
    result[result == ro.NA_Character] = None
    return result

result_df = r_rcra(input)
```

- If R is your “primary” language and Python is the “secondary” language. To use Python variables and functions inside an R process, there's [reticulated package](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/)

  - with [pandas version 2.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html), you can create pandas data frames directly in Arrow (instead of converting a pandas data frame into arrow object) and expose it to R

```
# in python: suppose you would like to create a pandas data frame df from some CSV file
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(#SOME CSV FILE#, dtype_backend='pyarrow')

# in R:
library(reticulate)
library(arrow)

pd <- import("pandas")
df = pd$read_csv(#SOME CSV FILE#, dtype_backend='pyarrow')
```

Both use Arrow as the underline in memory data object format.